# Openfire: Add user with subscription status as "both"

Tags: php, openfire

I am facing issue when i add user using [RestApi](https://github.com/gidkom/php-openfire-restapi)

```
include "vendor/autoload.php";
$api = new Gidkom\OpenFireRestApi\OpenFireRestApi;
$api->secret = "mySecretKey";
$api->host = "HostName";
$api->port = "9090";
$api->useSSL = false;
$api->plugin = "/plugins/restapi/v1";  // plugin
```

For adding user to Roster i am using following code

```
$jid="xyz@domainname";
//Add to roster
$data=$api->addToRoster("abc", $jid);
```

Which points to `OpenFireRestApi.php` which do have function named `addToRoster`

```
 /**
     * Adds to this OpenFire user's roster
     *
     * @param   string          $username       Username
     * @param   string          $jid            JID
     * @param   string|false    $name           Name         (Optional)
     * @param   int|false       $subscription   Subscription (Optional)
     * @return  json|false                     Json with data or error, or False when something went fully wrong
     */
    public function addToRoster($username, $jid, $name=false, $subscription=false)
    {
        $endpoint = '/users/'.$username.'/roster';
        return $this->doRequest('post', $endpoint, compact('jid','name','subscription'));
    }
```

So I've used

```
$data=$api->addToRoster("abc", $jid,"DummyName",3);
```

Where 3 is subscription type as both = 3 which is [mentioned.](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html)

But when i add user shows subscription type as **none** only.

> **UPDATE**

I came to know about [subscription plugin](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/subscription/readme.html)

So I've installed plugin configure it
[image]

Plugin itself says it will automatically subscribe both way.

Afterwards i've again tried with

```
$data=$api->addToRoster("abc", $jid);
```

Which aspects to be working but again subscriptions is **none** only.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with  `php-openfire-restapi` classes

Need to change name of parameters 
So do following changes :

```
//Add to roster
$username = "username in which you want to add roster";
$jid = "another users JID";
$nickname= "nick name of another user";
$subscription ="3";
$result = $api->addToRoster($username, $jid,$nickname,$subscription);
```

and change following line in `/src/Gidkom/OpenFireRestApi/OpenFireRestApi.php` file

```
public function addToRoster($username, $jid, $name=false, $subscription=false)
    {
        $nickname=$name;
        $subscriptionType=$subscription;
        $endpoint = '/users/'.$username.'/roster';
        return $this->doRequest('post', $endpoint, compact('jid','nickname','subscriptionType'));
    }
```

Here I have changed parameter names.

Good Luck.